# getting the absolute path of a <img/>

Tags: javascript, url, image, absolute-path

Using Javascript, is there a standard way to get the **absolute path** of an image? `img.getAttribute("src")` only returns the `src` attribute as it was declared in the HTML.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just do `.src`.

```
$('img')[0].src = '/images/foo.gif'
"/images/foo.gif"
$('img')[0].src
"http://stackoverflow.com/images/foo.gif"
$('img')[0].getAttribute('src')
"/images/foo.gif"
```

Comment: To clarify - `.src` actually does convert relative paths to absolute. Example: `var a = new Image(); a.src = '/a/../b'; alert(a.src)` will resolve correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that was so obvious :-))

Comment: When in doubt, check the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#dom-img-src): *“The `alt`, **`src`**, … IDL attributes must ***reflect*** the respective content attributes of the same name.”* Now, *“reflect”* here is defined in, https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-dom-interfaces.html#reflect

Answer (score 0):

For relative source path

```
  function getImageURI(imagePath) {
      if (imagePath.indexOf('http') == 0) {
        return imagePath
      }
      var rootPath = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
      var path = window.location.pathname;
      if (path.indexOf("/") == 0) {
          path = path.substring(1);
      }
      path = path.split("/", 1);
      if (path != "") {
          rootPath = rootPath + path + "/";
      }
      return rootPath + imagePath;
  }
```