# How do I get the absolute path for '<img src=''>' in node from the a response.body

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

So I want to use request-promise to pull the body of a page.  Once I have the page I want to collect all the  tags and get an array of src's of those images.  Assume the src attributes on a page have both relative and absolute paths.  I want an array of absolute paths for imgs on a page.  I know I can use some string manipulation and the npm path to build the absolute path but I wanted to find a better way of doing it.

```
var rp = require('request-promise'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');

var options = {
    uri: 'http://www.google.com',
    method: 'GET',
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
};

rp(options)
  .then (function (response) {
    $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
    var relativeLinks = $("img");
    relativeLinks.each( function() {
        var link = $(this).attr('src');
        console.log(link);
        if (link.startsWith('http')){
            console.log('abs');
        }
        else {
            console.log('rel');
        }
   });
});
```

results

```
  /logos/doodles/2016/phoebe-snetsingers-85th-birthday-5179281716019200-hp.gif
  rel
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting the absolute path of a <img/>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496491/getting-the-absolute-path-of-a-img)

Comment: @Midas This question is closely related, but not quite a duplicate of that other question because of the implementation differences between the DOM and jQuery in that case, and Cheerio in this case. Doing something like $(this) or $('img')[0].src won't return anything in Cheerio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an array of image links in your scenario, you can use [`url.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_resolve_from_to) to resolve relative `src` attributes of `img` tags with the request URL, resulting in an absolute URL. The array is passed to the final `then`; you can do other things with the array other than `console.log` if so desired.

```
var rp = require('request-promise'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    url = require('url'),
    base = 'http://www.google.com';

var options = {
    uri: base,
    method: 'GET',
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
};

rp(options)
    .then (function (response) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(response.body);

        return $('img').map(function () {
            return url.resolve(base, $(this).attr('src'));
        }).toArray();
    })
    .then(console.log);
```

This `url.resolve` will work for absolute or relative URLs (it resolves and returns the combined absolute URL when resolving from your request URL to a relative path, but when resolving from your request URL to an absolute URL it just returns the absolute URL). For example, with `img` tags on google with `/logos/cat.gif` and `https://test.com/dog.gif` as the `src` attributes, this would output:

```
[ 
    'http://www.google.com/logos/cat.gif',
    'https://test.com/dog.gif'
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Store your page URL as a variable use `url.resolve` to join the pieces together. In the Node REPL this works for both relative and absolute paths (hence the "resolving"):

```
$:~/Projects/test$ node
> var base = "https://www.google.com";
undefined
> var imageSrc = "/logos/doodles/2016/phoebe-snetsingers-85th-birthday-5179281716019200-hp.gif";
undefined
> var url = require('url');
undefined
> url.resolve(base, imageSrc);
'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/phoebe-snetsingers-85th-birthday-5179281716019200-hp.gif'
> imageSrc = base + imageSrc;
'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/phoebe-snetsingers-85th-birthday-5179281716019200-hp.gif'
> url.resolve(base, imageSrc);
'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/phoebe-snetsingers-85th-birthday-5179281716019200-hp.gif'
```

Your code would change to something like:

```
var rp = require('request-promise'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    url = require('url'),
    base = 'http://www.google.com';

var options = {
    uri: base,
    method: 'GET',
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
};

rp(options)
  .then (function (response) {
    $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
    var relativeLinks = $("img");
    relativeLinks.each( function() {
        var link = $(this).attr('src');
        var fullImagePath = url.resolve(base, link); // should be absolute 
        console.log(link);
        if (link.startsWith('http')){
            console.log('abs');
        }
        else {
            console.log('rel');
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using jQuery, so you could

```
$('img').each(function(i, e) {
    console.log(e.src)
});
```

If you use `src` it will expand relative paths to absolute ones.

Comment: Correct, but `src` is not a jQuery attribute. It's standard Javascript.

Comment: It's a DOM attribute - you don't have to use jQuery for _everything_

Comment: To be a little pedantic, he's using Cheerio, which is a NodeJS module that uses jQuery-like syntax for traversing the DOM. Also, in this case accessing the src attribute won't help because it will still return a root-relative URL (or whatever is in the DOM) when he needs the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2022 and [url.resolve](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_resolve_from_to) is deprecated now.

Here is how I do it (works both for a 'href' and img 'src'):

```
import URI from 'urijs'

function absolutizeUri(maybeRelativeUri: string, baseUri: string): string {
    if (!maybeRelativeUri || maybeRelativeUri.length === 0) {
        return ''
    }
    let uri = new URI(maybeRelativeUri);
    if (uri.is('relative')) {
        uri = ur.absoluteTo(baseUri)
    }
    return uri.toString()
}

// ...
const baseUri = 'http://www.google.com'
const src = absolutizeUri($(this).attr('src'), baseUri)
```